# Wizard / model dialog boxes in Sitecore8

Tags: sitecore, wizard, dialog

I want to create a wizard in sitecore 8, how can i do it? is there any way to overwrite pipelines and display normal web pages as dialog boxes? please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at Sitecore SPEAK you can create dialog controls or full applications within Sitecore 8. You can create your wizard with the SPEAK controls.

Here are some videos on Sitecore SPEAK. (the videos are on Sitecore 7.1 but the process of building SPEAK applications are the same)

https://www.youtube.com/user/JakobHChristensen/videos

There is good documentation on the doc site too:
https://doc.sitecore.net/speak

and Martina's blog: 
http://mhwelander.net/2014/06/27/speak-for-newbies-part-1-creating-a-new-application/

I have a few SPEAK demo applications on GitHub here.
https://github.com/sobek1985/EntityServiceDemo

https://github.com/sobek1985/WallpaperManager

https://github.com/sobek1985/SitecoreSPEAKBulkWorkflows